# Changing button icon of SplitApp master view

Tags: sapui5

How can one change the default button icon of the [SplitApp](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html) master view?

[image]

Let's say I want to use this [icon](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/iconExplorer.html) instead of the default:

```
"sap-icon://filter"
```

I was trying [setHomeIcon](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html#setHomeIcon) property of SplitApp but it did not work.

Here is jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/ruzoyezuli/1/edit?html,js,output), which I found. It would be nice to change icon there. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon you would like to customize belongs to the master button of the [SplitContainer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html) which is the base for the SplitApp.

SplitContainer does not provide an API for setting the masterButton icon. However you can register for the [master button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html#event:masterButton) event and obtain the button there. This works only with the following conditions:

- You need to prepend the view ID to the SplitApp control ID using `this.createId("mySplitApp")`. If you use XML views this is done automatically.
- You rely on the naming of the button. If SAP decides to change the name this won't work.

The following event handler implementation will do the job:

```
oSplitApp.attachMasterButton(function(event) {
    if (event.getParameter("show")) { 
        const button = this.byId(this.createId("mySplitApp-MasterBtn"));
        if (button) {
            button.setIcon("sap-icon://filter");
        }
    }
}, this);
```

The example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/hopaxoyese/2/edit?html,js,output).